# Run OSX on external drive

Tags: external-disk, development

I use a Surface Pro 3 (will upgrade to the 4 in a few months hopefully) and want to develop iOS applications but I don't want to buy a Mac.
I've heard about Hackintosh, but I was wondering: can I install OSX on an external drive with Xcode etc and still have development performance?

How would I go about this?

Comment: I suppose that you could have the install disk on a USB and a blank USB hard drive, and install OS X onto it. Or install EFI and put a backup of your mac (if you have one) onto the hard drive

Comment: And it begs the question, is a Surface Pro 4 even compatible with the Mac O/S? Perhaps checking Hackintosh forums bight be a better place to start? Not all PCs will work with the Mac O/S and it might indeed be better to just get a new (or used) Mac Mini for development purposes as a hackintosh is an unsupported configuration and you could end up with something that only runs on your hackintosh and not an actual Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend getting a [Mac mini](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/) for ~$500.

You'll likely spend close to that getting the right hardware into your PC anyway, and with the mini you'll end-up with a legitimate system.  If you'll be doing iOS development, you'll want to have a real Apple system with support, instead of something you'll have to try to support yourself.

Since your asking this question on this forum, I'm guessing you'll have difficulties with the latter.